# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ramaelectricstore.wsgi.application'; 'ramaelectricstore.wsgi' is not a package

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am traying to deploy Django app on AWS EC2 instance but after running this command
4-144:~/ramaelectricstore/ramaelectricstore$ gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 ramaelectricstore.wsgi.application

I am facing this Error please help me

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ramaelectricstore.wsgi.application'; 'ramaelectricstore.wsgi' is not a package

Answer (score 0):

@Amar Thakur- Have you tried the following.

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 ramaelectricstore.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

This error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ramaelectricstore.wsgi.application'; 'ramaelectricstore.wsgi' is not a package` may also occur if you have named the main program file you created as `ramaelectricstore.wsgi` or another your file has the name `ramaelectricstore.wsgi` in the same folder from which you run your program. Python will consider your program file as a module and try to find something in it that is naturally not in it. About where Python is looking for modules, see [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

In this case, rename your program file so that its name does not equal with the name of the imported module.